# Spring rabbitmq testing - RabbitListenerTestHarness doesn't find any listener

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-test, spring-rabbit

I'm trying to write some tests for a spring rabbitmq application.

From [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#testing), I found the example using RabbitListenerTestHarness.

I created a Test in spring that looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyMain.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    @Test
    public void myTest(){
        RabbitProperties.Listener listener = harness.getSpy("test_consumer2");
    }
}
```

In the source, I have a bean that creates the configuration to rabbitmq which has the annotation `@RabbitListenerTest(capture = true, spy = true)`.

Also, in the source I have the following consumer:

```
@Component
```

public class TestConsumerStub {

```
@RabbitListener(
        id = "test_consumer2",
        queues = "my_queue"
)
public void testHandler(){

}
```

For some reason, the harness (`RabbitListenerTestHarness harness`) object from the tests, is not loaded in the context that consumer. The following variable is null:
`RabbitProperties.Listener listener = harness.getSpy("test_consumer2");`

Any idea what did I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debuging the `RabbitListenerTestHarness` bean I figured out which was the problem. I was using `spring-boot-starter-amqp` for spring rabbit and for `spring-rabbit-test` I was writing explicitly the version, which was not matching the version of `spring-amqp`. I updated `spring-boot-starter-parent` version to `1.4.0` which was installing `spring-ampq` version `1.6.1` which is the same version of my `spring-rabbit-test`.